# Is there a better way to generate python classes for tables in a database?

Tags: python, mysql

I am working with a database where I want to be able to have classes for each table.  Basically I want to input paramaters when creating the class objects and return a dataframe based on the parameters.

I started going through and manually creating these classes and I thought that there just must be a better way to do this that I am not aware of.

Here is an example of one of the simpler classes:

```
class CkMaster(DBHelper):
def __init__(self, accountNo='%', year='%', checkNo='%', checkDate='%', amount='%', name='%', clearDate='%', clearTime='%', status='%', comments='%'):
    super().__init__()
    self.table = self.fetch(sql=f"SELECT * FROM ckmaster WHERE accountNo LIKE {'accountNo'} AND year LIKE {'year'} AND checkNo LIKE {'checkNo'} AND checkDate LIKE {'checkDate'} AND amount LIKE {'amount'} AND name LIKE {'name'} AND clearDate LIKE {'clearDate'} AND clearTime LIKE {'clearTime'} AND status LIKE {'status'} AND comments LIKE {'comments'}")


def to_df(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.table)
    self.df = df
```

All of the fields are laid out in in the init function when creating self.table and as options in the **init** method.

It seems like there must be a way to do this for every table in the database, but I can't figure out how exactly to do it.  Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: You might want to look into using an existing ORM rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: Is there any that you would recommend?  I am a bit of a novice.

Comment: Check sqlalchemy https://www.sqlalchemy.org/